# Adding a directory from the host filesystem to the docker filesystem (not in a dockerfile)

Tags: virtualization, docker, dockerhub

I have a docker image already. I want to be able to add a directory from the host file system to the docker filesystem. I know that if I am using a base image, I could use the ADD command in the dockerfile but I am not actually using a base image, I want to build a new docker image based on my image with some directories added to it from my host file system. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create another docker image based your image.

```
FROM base-image-name

ADD host_dir  /destination_dir
```

Comment: did you tag your image ? you need to put the tag name of your image to work

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a new image, just run it like this:

> docker run your_image -v host_dir:local_dir